# WordPress API - can't get pages tags

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

In WP admin panel if we look at **Pages** and **Posts** tables we can see **Tags** column ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmSaK.png)) in both tables.

If we get **Posts** trough WP API in **Post** object we can find **Tags** attribute. But if we get **Pages** trough WP API - there are not **tags** attribute in **Page** object ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA4Qm.png)). Is there any other option to get **Pages** with associated **Tags**?

Thanks for any help!